# Finding data but excluding multiple characters if they have prefixes

Tags: regex

I have some text as follows:

`<134>222 2023-06-15T23:00:27Z opchs14mlm APPID 17848 - [flags:"278528"; ifdir:"inbound\]"; loguid:"{0x90f9aacb,0x18ca68fc,0xa48e71f3,0xc0419663}"; suppressed_logs:"1"]`

The first part up to the [*data*] is the header, the rest is structured data within the square brackets. The data can contain `]` but is always prefixed as `\\]` when inside the structured data part.

Using the following works ok: `^(<\d.*>)[ ]?(\d*)\s(.*?){7}\s\[(.*)\]`

The problem is the string can end up having mangled unformatted data at the end, e.g.

`<134>222 2023-06-15T23:00:27Z opchs14mlm APPID 17848 - [flags:"278528"; ifdir:"inbound\]"; loguid:"{0x90f9aacb,0x18ca68fc,0xa48e71f3,0xc0419663}"; suppressed_logs:"1"]` **some random text ] here.**

And can, and does, include `]`. So the regex needs to essentially find the last `]` but ignore `some text ] here`. I know I probably need to use negative lookadhead but I cannot figure it out, i.e. inside `[]` there are never `]` but there can be `\\]`, and outside this is the wild west.

i.e. my regex is only working when there is no bad data at the end because the last part is being greedy I presume.

The sample can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/PhV9pN/3

Comment: _The data can contain ']' but is always prefixed as '\\]'_ Coud you give an example?  In your initial data sample, the `]` in `ifdir:"inbound]";` is unescaped.  Or is it because of StackOverflow's text editor?  Try `\\]` then, or use code formatting.

Comment: Where is the regex being used? Can PCRE verbs be used?

Comment: "ignore 'some text ] here" not to be pedantic but none of your examples include this. You're asking to find the last `]` but then saying you don't want to get it. What do you actually want?

Comment: "Using the following works ok" works ok for *what*? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Regex suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/YVj9Vt/1) :

```
^(\<\d+\>) ?(\d+) ?([^[]+)(\[(?:\w+:"[^"]+"(?:; |\]))+)
```

Based on your input sample

```
<134>222 2023-06-15T23:00:27Z opchs14mlm APPID 17848 - [flags:"278528"; ifdir:"inbound\]"; loguid:"{0x90f9aacb,0x18ca68fc,0xa48e71f3,0xc0419663}"; suppressed_logs:"1"] some random text ] here.
```

You get :

- group1 : `<134>`
- group2 : `222`
- group3 : `2023-06-15T23:00:27Z opchs14mlm APPID 17848 -`
- group4 : `[flags:"278528"; ifdir:"inbound\]"; loguid:"{0x90f9aacb,0x18ca68fc,0xa48e71f3,0xc0419663}"; suppressed_logs:"1"]`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the square brackets are not nested and a negative lookahead is supported, you can use:

```
^(<\d+>)(\d+)\s?(.*?)\s+\[([^\\\]]*(?:\\+.[^\\\]]*)*)]
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(<\d+>)` Capture **group 1**, match `<` 1+ digits `>`
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `\s?` Match an optional whitespace char
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 3**, match any character, as few as possible
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `[^\\\]]*` Match optional chars other than `\\` and `]`
  - `(?:\\+.[^\\\]]*)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ times a `\` char followed by any character, and then match again optional chars other than `\\` and `]`
- `)` Close group 4
- `]` Match `]`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RECXfW/1).